# Problems with Zod validation and React hook form

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form, zod

i am using Shadcn, Zod and React hood form in my nextjs 14 application with app router. This i my code:

```js
"use client";

import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as z from "zod";


import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";

const profileFormSchema = z.object({
  full_name: z.string().min(2).max(20),
  address: z.string().min(2).max(50),
  phone_number: z.string().min(2).max(20),
  picture: typeof window === "undefined" ? z.any() : z.instanceof(File)
});

export type ProfileFormSchemaType = z.infer<typeof profileFormSchema>;

export default function ProfileForm() {
  const form = useForm<ProfileFormSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(profileFormSchema),
  });

  async function onSubmit(values: ProfileFormSchemaType) {
    console.log(values);
  }

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form
        onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        className="space-y-8 rounded-tr-2xl rounded-tl-2xl border p-8"
      >
       ...
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="picture"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Picture</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input
                  accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png"
                  type="file"
                  multiple={false}
                  {...field}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <Button
          disabled={form.formState.isSubmitting}
          type="submit"
          className={"block mx-auto px-8"}
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

If you are wondering why i defined picture like that i fixed an issue using this discussion on [github](https://github.com/blitz-js/blitz/discussions/2292#discussioncomment-826778).

The problem i am facing is that when i upload a file on my browser to the picture field, i get the message "Input not instance of File" which is the error message from Zod because it doesnt pass the validation somehow?

i have tried some of the solutions in this [issue](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/387) but they dont work. anyone know how to fix this? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is directly related to how you define the picture object.
According to the react-form-hook docs one of their explict rules is that:

You should avoid providing undefined as a default value, as it conflicts with the default state of a controlled component.

Try adjusting that and find another way to adjust the default value.
Here is a link to their docs: https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform